The Stutter Gradle plugin does not run any tests
The org.ajoberstar.stutter plugin ( https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-stutter ) is a tool for compatibility testing.
But I cannot make it run any compatibility tests.
It did not work with Gradle 8.9, it did not work with Gradle 8.6 (8.6 is the most recent version mentioned in the plugin docs).

I create a project with ~/Downloads/tmpgradle/8.6/gradlew init:

type of project to generate:        4: Gradle plugin
implementation language:            1: Groovy
build script DSL:                   2: Groovy
Project name (default: greetingPlugin):         greetingPlugin
Generate build using new APIs and behavior:     no


I insert a prinln() into the plugin's apply() function, and a println() into the (generated) functional test. I copy the functionalTest directory to the compatTest directory and rename the class.
I modify build.gradle to include the stutter plugin:


plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'org.ajoberstar.stutter' version '1.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation libs.spock.core
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        greeting {
            id = 'org.example.greeting'
            implementationClass = 'org.example.GreetingPluginPlugin'
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    functionalTest {
    }
}

configurations.functionalTestImplementation.extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation)
configurations.functionalTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly)

// Add a task to run the functional tests
tasks.register('functionalTest', Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.functionalTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.functionalTest.runtimeClasspath
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

gradlePlugin.testSourceSets.add(sourceSets.functionalTest)

tasks.named('check') {
    // Run the functional tests as part of `check`
    dependsOn(tasks.functionalTest)
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
dependencies {
    // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    compatTestImplementation libs.spock.core
    compatTestRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}
stutter {
  // if true, only match min/max within that otherwise matches your compatibility specs in each Gradle major version
//  sparse = false // defaults to true

    matrices {
        java13 {
            javaToolchain {
                languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(13)
            }
            gradleVersions {
                compatible '6.2.1'
                compatible '8.6'
            }
        }

//    // a matrix of tests running against Java 8
//    java8 {
//      javaToolchain {
//        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)
//      }
//      gradleVersions {
//        compatibleRange '3.0', '4.0' // include 3.0 <= version < 4.0
//        compatibleRange '4.2' // include 4.2 <= version
//        compatible '2.14', '1.2' // include 2.14 and 1.12 specifically
//        incompatible '3.3' // exclude 3.3 even if included above
//      }
//    }
//
//
//    // name can be anything
//    jdkNine {
//      javaToolchain {
//        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(9)
//      }
//      gradleVersions {
//        compatibleRange '4.0' // include 4.0 <= version
//      }
//    }
  }

  // You do have to specify compatible Gradle versions for all Java versions you run Gradle with

  // If you have a lot of tests, or otherwise just don't want to test every Gradle version that you say is compatible,
  // use sparse = true. This will greatly limit the number of versions you test against, but should do the job of
  // verifying compatibility.
  // e.g.  compatible '2.14' and compatibleRange '3.0'
  //       matches '2.14', '3.0', '3.5.1', '4.0', '4.7' (presuming 4.7 is the latest available 4.x)
}

//does not help:
//configurations.compatTestImplementation.extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation)
//configurations.compatTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly)


I run ./gradlew stutterWriteLocks and ./gradlew clean compatTest --warning-mode all.

The project directory contains:
~/stackoverflow/greetingPlugin$ tree
.
├── gradle
│   ├── libs.versions.toml
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── plugin
│   ├── build
│   │   ├── classes
│   │   │   └── groovy
│   │   │       ├── compatTest
│   │   │       │   └── org
│   │   │       │       └── example
│   │   │       │           └── GreetingPluginPluginCompatTest.class
│   │   │       └── main
│   │   │           └── org
│   │   │               └── example
│   │   │                   ├── GreetingPluginPlugin$_apply_closure1$_closure2.class
│   │   │                   ├── GreetingPluginPlugin$_apply_closure1.class
│   │   │                   └── GreetingPluginPlugin.class
│   │   ├── generated
│   │   │   └── sources
│   │   │       └── annotationProcessor
│   │   │           └── groovy
│   │   │               ├── compatTest
│   │   │               └── main
│   │   ├── pluginDescriptors
│   │   │   └── org.example.greeting.properties
│   │   ├── pluginUnderTestMetadata
│   │   │   └── plugin-under-test-metadata.properties
│   │   ├── reports
│   │   │   └── tests
│   │   │       ├── compatTestJava13Gradle6.2.1
│   │   │       │   ├── css
│   │   │       │   │   ├── base-style.css
│   │   │       │   │   └── style.css
│   │   │       │   ├── index.html
│   │   │       │   └── js
│   │   │       │       └── report.js
│   │   │       └── compatTestJava13Gradle8.6
│   │   │           ├── css
│   │   │           │   ├── base-style.css
│   │   │           │   └── style.css
│   │   │           ├── index.html
│   │   │           └── js
│   │   │               └── report.js
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── main
│   │   │       └── META-INF
│   │   │           └── gradle-plugins
│   │   │               └── org.example.greeting.properties
│   │   ├── test-results
│   │   │   ├── compatTestJava13Gradle6.2.1
│   │   │   │   └── binary
│   │   │   │       ├── output.bin
│   │   │   │       ├── output.bin.idx
│   │   │   │       └── results.bin
│   │   │   └── compatTestJava13Gradle8.6
│   │   │       └── binary
│   │   │           ├── output.bin
│   │   │           ├── output.bin.idx
│   │   │           └── results.bin
│   │   └── tmp
│   │       ├── compatTestJava13Gradle6.2.1
│   │       │   ├── jar_extract_11168663823107129072_tmp
│   │       │   ├── jar_extract_1507282802988250170_tmp
│   │       │   └── jar_extract_7058108455941420678_tmp
│   │       ├── compatTestJava13Gradle8.6
│   │       │   ├── jar_extract_1158481335806899552_tmp
│   │       │   ├── jar_extract_5215173060414151702_tmp
│   │       │   └── jar_extract_7036217941087640325_tmp
│   │       ├── compileCompatTestGroovy
│   │       │   └── groovy-java-stubs
│   │       └── compileGroovy
│   │           └── groovy-java-stubs
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── compatTest
│   │   │   └── groovy
│   │   │       └── org
│   │   │           └── example
│   │   │               └── GreetingPluginPluginCompatTest.groovy
│   │   ├── functionalTest
│   │   │   └── groovy
│   │   │       └── org
│   │   │           └── example
│   │   │               └── GreetingPluginPluginFunctionalTest.groovy
│   │   ├── main
│   │   │   ├── groovy
│   │   │   │   └── org
│   │   │   │       └── example
│   │   │   │           └── GreetingPluginPlugin.groovy
│   │   │   └── resources
│   │   └── test
│   │       ├── groovy
│   │       │   └── org
│   │       │       └── example
│   │       │           └── GreetingPluginPluginTest.groovy
│   │       └── resources
│   └── stutter.lockfile
└── settings.gradle

63 directories, 39 files

The gradle output is:
$ ./gradlew clean compatTest --warning-mode all
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-19' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-21' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :plugin:clean
> Task :plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :plugin:compileGroovy
> Task :plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :plugin:processResources
> Task :plugin:classes
> Task :plugin:compileCompatTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :plugin:compileCompatTestGroovy
> Task :plugin:processCompatTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :plugin:compatTestClasses
> Task :plugin:pluginUnderTestMetadata

> Task :plugin:compatTestJava13Gradle6.2.1
The automatic loading of test framework implementation dependencies has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Declare the desired test framework directly on the test suite or explicitly declare the test framework implementation dependencies on the test's runtime classpath. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#test_framework_implementation_dependencies
No test executed. This behavior has been deprecated. This will fail with an error in Gradle 9.0. There are test sources present but no test was executed. Please check your test configuration. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#test_task_fail_on_no_test_executed

> Task :plugin:compatTestJava13Gradle8.6
> Task :plugin:compatTestJava13
> Task :plugin:compatTest

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
8 actionable tasks: 8 executed

You see that Gradle says that no tests were executed. This is true, I would see the messages from the test and the plugin, I enabled them via tasks.withType(Test) { testLogging.showStandardStreams = true } and I see the messages when I run integrationTest.
There are messages about missing java executables, but AFAIK Gradle would download them if they are necessary.
$ ls -lF /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 окт 19  2023 src.zip -> lib/src.zip

(All three poin to the same lib/src.zip)
What am I doing wrong?

In this particular case, the problem was that
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

did not apply to compatTest (but functionalTest worked, it must be due to laziness).
I prefer
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

instead.
The full plugin/build.gradle for Gradle 8.9:
plugins {
    // Apply the Java Gradle plugin development plugin to add support for developing Gradle plugins
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'

    // Apply the Groovy plugin to add support for Groovy
    id 'groovy'

    id 'org.ajoberstar.stutter' version '1.0.0'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

// !!stutter {{
// otherwise: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ... compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime ...
java {
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
// }} !!stutter


// !!stutter {{
// for a real modern example, see stutter { ... } in https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-stutter/blob/main/build.gradle.kts
stutter {
  // if true, only match min/max within that otherwise matches your compatibility specs in each Gradle major version
  //sparse = false // defaults to true

  matrices {
    java11 {
      javaToolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
      }
      gradleVersions {
        compatibleRange '6.0', '6.9.3'
      }
    }
  }
}
// }} !!stutter


dependencies {
    // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    testImplementation libs.spock.core
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

// !!stutter {{
    compatTestImplementation libs.spock.core
    compatTestRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
// }} !!stutter
}

gradlePlugin {
    // Define the plugin
    plugins {
        greeting {
            id = 'org.example.greeting'
            implementationClass = 'org.example.UsestutterPlugin'
        }
    }
}

// Add a source set for the functional test suite
sourceSets {
    functionalTest {
    }
}

configurations.functionalTestImplementation.extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation)
configurations.functionalTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly)

// Add a task to run the functional tests
tasks.register('functionalTest', Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.functionalTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.functionalTest.runtimeClasspath
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

gradlePlugin.testSourceSets.add(sourceSets.functionalTest)

tasks.named('check') {
    // Run the functional tests as part of `check`
    dependsOn(tasks.functionalTest)
}

// !!stutter {{
tasks.withType(Test) { // tasks.withType() to include compatTest
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
// }} !!stutter


// {{ show running tests
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    beforeTest { desc -> println(" $desc.className $desc.name ...")}
    afterTest { desc, res -> println(" $desc.className $desc.name $res")}
    afterSuite {desc, res -> println("after suite [$desc.name] $desc.className: $res")}
}
// }} show running tests


Diff from what was initially generated:
--- a/plugin/build.gradle
+++ b/plugin/build.gradle
@@ -11,6 +11,8 @@ plugins {
 
     // Apply the Groovy plugin to add support for Groovy
     id 'groovy'
+
+    id 'org.ajoberstar.stutter' version '1.0.0'
 }
 
 repositories {
@@ -18,11 +20,43 @@ repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }
 
+// !!stutter {{
+// otherwise: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ... compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime ...
+java {
+    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
+}
+// }} !!stutter
+
+
+// !!stutter {{
+// for a real modern example, see stutter { ... } in https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-stutter/blob/main/build.gradle.kts
+stutter {
+  // if true, only match min/max within that otherwise matches your compatibility specs in each Gradle major version
+  //sparse = false // defaults to true
+
+  matrices {
+    java11 {
+      javaToolchain {
+        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
+      }
+      gradleVersions {
+        compatibleRange '6.0', '6.9.3'
+      }
+    }
+  }
+}
+// }} !!stutter
+
+
 dependencies {
     // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
     testImplementation libs.spock.core
-
     testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
+
+// !!stutter {{
+    compatTestImplementation libs.spock.core
+    compatTestRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
+// }} !!stutter
 }
 
 gradlePlugin {
@@ -58,7 +92,24 @@ tasks.named('check') {
     dependsOn(tasks.functionalTest)
 }
 
-tasks.named('test') {
+// !!stutter {{
+tasks.withType(Test) { // tasks.withType() to include compatTest
     // Use JUnit Jupiter for unit tests.
     useJUnitPlatform()
 }
+// }} !!stutter
+
+
+// {{ show running tests
+tasks.withType(Test) {
+    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
+}
+tasks.withType(Test) {
+    beforeTest { desc -> println(" $desc.className $desc.name ...")}
+    afterTest { desc, res -> println(" $desc.className $desc.name $res")}
+    afterSuite {desc, res -> println("after suite [$desc.name] $desc.className: $res")}
+}
+// }} show running tests
+

The directory structure:
$ tree plugin/
plugin/
├── build.gradle
├── src
│   ├── compatTest
│   │   └── groovy
│   │       └── org
│   │           └── example
│   │               └── MyCompatTest.groovy
│   ├── functionalTest
│   │   └── groovy
│   │       └── org
│   │           └── example
│   │               └── UsestutterPluginFunctionalTest.groovy
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── groovy
│   │   │   └── org
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── UsestutterPlugin.groovy
│   │   └── resources
│   └── test
│       ├── groovy
│       │   └── org
│       │       └── example
│       │           └── UsestutterPluginTest.groovy
│       └── resources
└── stutter.lockfile

19 directories, 6 files

For a start, MyCompatTest.groovy may be a copy of the functional test.
